# Python Question. TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, function, arguments, typeerror, self

I am glad for any help anyone can provide! I am working on a code for a basic Fourier Analysis program, and to calculate the set of coefficients I realized out of efficiency's sake I wanted to multiply functions so it can provide a single function that can be numerically integrated. I got some help and now have an 'operable' class which should help me do this. Here is the code for the 'operable' class, above the code for my program:

```
class operable:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.f(x)

def op_to_function_op(op):
    def function_op(self, operand):
        def f(x):
            return op(self(x), operand(x))
        return operable(f)
    return function_op

for name, op in [(name, getattr(operator, name)) for name in dir(operator) if "__" in name]:
    try:
        op(1,2)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        setattr(operable, name, op_to_function_op(op))
```

Now I am calling a function which is operable, from this function call here on the 6th line.

```
def findFourierCoefficients(function, T, kmax):
    coefficientsA = [] #will have size kmax
    coefficientsB = []
    for i in range(0, kmax):
        #find the coefficient a_k
        integrandA = integrandForAK(function, i) #HERE IS THE FUNCTION CALL
        integrationA = simpson(integrandA, 0, T, nValue)
        coefficientA = (2/T) * integrationA
        coefficientsA.append(coefficientA) 
    return coefficientsA
```

I've looked online and found that I need to provide a third parameter to my function, and I have done this below with the parameter 'self'.

```
@operable
def integrandForAK(self, fun, k):
    def specialCosineFunction(x):
        return np.cos(k * omega * x)
    functionToIntegrate = fun * specialCosineFunction
    #functionToIntegrate = getFunctionProduct(fun, specialCosineFunction)
    return functionToIntegrate
```

I am still getting this error, that it only takes two positional arguments when three were given - but I have made another argument in my function so I don't know why it doesn't recognize it. Thank you again for any help anyone can provide, I am fairly new to this level of coding - python in particular is newer to me. All the best!

Comment: Welcome to the community. In order for us to better help you, I'd suggest first editing the format of `class operable`, especially correcting the indentation.  Right now, it's confusing to me what belong to the class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure self is a parameter, but does not take an argument, so you will still get the error where it's only recognizing 2 arguments

Comment: Is `op_to_function_op(op)` meant to belong to the `operable` class?